# Angular2 - http://localhost:4200/ being appended with api call why?

Tags: angular, http, request, append, localhost

just start learning `angular2` followed the `heroes` tutorial. I am making a create request, the URL is perfectly fine, the parameters are fine. But I am still confused why `http://localhost:4200/` is being appended with my `API` call, and because of that the URL gets totally changed, and the calls failed.please shed some light over this issue. I googled a lot but could find the reason.

**My Create Method**

```
 create(user: object): Promise<any> {
    return this.http
        .post('localhost/usmanProject/api/web/v1/users?access-token=n-EJtZiejtz5RSVWe-U14G4kCnPWMKf0', user, { headers: this.headers })
        .toPromise()
        .then(res => res.json().data)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

[image]

Comment: How does the resulting url look like and where do you see that that is appended?

Comment: in my console sir wait let me add a screen shot

Comment: please see the image

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to add your protocol for your URL. Otherwise, it's a relative URL:

```
.post('http://localhost/usmanProject/api/web/v1/users?access-token=n-EJtZiejtz5RSVWe-U14G4kCnPWMKf0', user, { headers: this.headers })
```

Comment: but method is get in the controller then

Answer (score 1):

Your Url should be like url:string ="www.example.com";

It should not be like  url:string =" 'www.example.com' ";

Answer (score 0):

`http://localhost:4200/` is the url the page is initially loaded from.

You should either add the full url like

```
.post('//localhost:4200/usmanProject/api/web/v1/users?access-token=n-EJtZiejtz5RSVWe-U14G4kCnPWMKf0', user, { headers: this.headers })
```

or

```
.post('http://localhost:4200/usmanProject/api/web/v1/users?access-token=n-EJtZiejtz5RSVWe-U14G4kCnPWMKf0', user, { headers: this.headers })
```

or no host part at all

```
.post('usmanProject/api/web/v1/users?access-token=n-EJtZiejtz5RSVWe-U14G4kCnPWMKf0', user, { headers: this.headers })
```

Answer (score 0):

Experienced this problem and solved it through separation of concern by creating a app.settings.ts file that will contain the end point to where the api is being served from

```
export class AppSettings {
   public static get FOLDER_ENDPOINT(): string {
     return 'http://127.0.0.1:8000';
   } 
}
```

Then create a service and import the app.settings as below

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http/src/headers';
import { Http, Response, RequestOptions, ResponseContentType } from 
'@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import { AppSettings } from '../app.settings';


@Injectable()
export class FormsubmitService {

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

listAll(data: any): Observable<any> {
  return this.http
    .get(`${AppSettings.FOLDER_ENDPOINT}/list-files`);
 }
}
```

In your app.component.html add a function that triggers the api call

```
<button (click)="loadData()" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">load data</button>
```

Then in your app.component.ts you write your method

```
loadData() {
  this._fbService.listAll('').subscribe(data => {
   console.log('Data returned', data);
  });
}
```