# What could be causing localhost:4200 to be added in front of route call?

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm trying to make a call to an API, but for some reason localhost:4200 is being added in front of my route call to localhost:3000.

I've looked through my code several times and have another API call that is functioning fine with the same type of code that I am using to do this API call.

Here is my service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

interface Tweet {
  name: string;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
  export class TweetService {
    private url = environment.tweetsAPI;

    httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
    };

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    getTweets() {
      console.log(this.url);
      return this.http.get(this.url);
    }
  }
```

Here is my route:

```
app.route('/get-tweets').get((req, res) => {
  T.get('search/tweets', { q: 'iowa state since:2018-07-11 #gameday -filter:media -filter:retweets', count: 10 }, function(err, data, response) {
    let filteredTweets = [];
    _.each(data, userObj => {
      filteredTweets.push(userObj);
    })
    return res.status(200).json({
      message: 'Successfully returned tweets',
      tweets: filteredTweets
    })
  })
})
```

And inside my environment.ts file:

```
tweetsAPI: 'http:/localhost:3000/get-tweets'
```

Getting this error:

```
ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 404, statusText: "Not Found", url: "http://localhost:4200/localhost:3000/get-tweets", ok: false, …}
```

Comment: Single forward slash in the URI? `'http:/` instead of `'http://`?

Comment: Should this: `tweetsAPI: 'http:/localhost:3000/get-tweets'` be this: `tweetsAPI: 'http://localhost:3000/get-tweets'`? Missing slash?

Comment: You can also http-query Angular files. I think Angular treats it as own project files because of the missing double slash. Please change to `http://`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 - http://localhost:4200/ being appended with api call why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46205569/angular2-http-localhost4200-being-appended-with-api-call-why)

Comment: @bendataclear you are correct, dumb mistake, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace tweetsAPI: **'http:/localhost:3000/get-tweets'**
with 
tweetsAPI: **'http://localhost:3000/get-tweets'**

Answer (score 0):

> [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46205569/angular2-http-localhost4200-being-appended-with-api-call-why)

You need to add your protocol for your URL. Otherwise, it's a relative URL:

```
.post('http:/localhost:3000/get-tweets', { headers: this.headers })
```